# Make an OS X Installer Think that it is on Snow Leopard, not Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac, compatibility

Is there a way to make Leopard think that it is Snow Leopard, for the sake of installing newer software?

(At my own risk, understandably.)

Comment: Shouldn't this read: "Make *an installer* think OS X Leopard is Snow Leopard?" I doubt it's about OS X itself, but I guess the installers should be fooled. Still then I think MarkM is right: why would a software vendor claim 10.6 is required if it would run on 10.5 as well?

Comment: Truth is, I just need to run the iPhone SDK 4 installer so that I can compile something against iOS 4 for testing. Oh well. (See my comment on MarkM.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to convince Installer itself but you can modify an installer's packages to ignore it's checks. All bets are off however as to it working (or even installing correctly) depending on how it's packaged and what tools they use in the pre and post install portions.

Not recommended at all.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Entirely depends on the package - you'll have to reverse engineer or look at the pre and post scripts along with the Info.plist (all available when you choose Show Package Contents). If you're dealing with a multi-package (.mpkg) you'll have to perform it on each of the child packages as well. Possible but most likely not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

No, Snow Leopard uses a different kernel than Leopard and has many different libraries.

A Snow Leopard upgrade is about $30US. That's not so much that you should consider trying to trick applications into thinking the OS is newer. I'd just get the upgrade if I were you.

Comment: Generally you are right about the upgrade. I would do it but... This is a borrowed MacBook that's being returned in a few hours. I wanted to give iOS4 SDK GM a quick spin here. I have it in the office already. Oh well. Later then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to iPhone SDK 4, then doesn't that mean you also have access to Snow Leopard -- my understanding is that because it's a requirement Apple has included Snow Leopard in the iPhone developer site for free (for registered iPhone developers).